# Is there a way to check if a savedlist is empty in Unidata?

Tags: unidata

is there a way to check if a savedlist is empty in Unidata (and if so generate a new savedlist)?

The pseudo code would essentially be:
IF savedlist1 IS EMPTY
SELECT PERSON SAMPLE 1
SAVE.LIST savedlist1

(if not empty, leave the original savedlist1 as is)

An alternative approach is if a SELECT statement does not return any results, is there a way to prevent a savedlist from being created, like this:

*create a savedlist in case nothing is selected for what I actually want*
SELECT PERSON SAMPLE 1
SAVE.LIST savedlist1

*create the savedlist of what I actually want, if it fails use the one above*
SELECT PERSON WITH NAME EQ 'Bruce' REQUIRE.SELECT
SAVE.LIST savedlist1 (*IF selection returned results*)

I have tried adding REQUIRE.SELECT and SELECT.ONLY, but by the time it gets to the SAVE.LIST command the selection is terminated, and I just get *"No active select list, creating empty saved list."*  Trying to add either to the SAVELIST line results in a syntax error.

The final way I thought to manage this is by appending the select statement to an existing savedlist, but I have not had luck with MERGE.LIST or TO with that:
SELECT PERSON WITH NAME EQ 'Bruce' TO savedlist1
*TO can't be used with SELECT/COUNT/SUM/TAPE*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building a paragraph, if yes, you can check for @SYSTEM.RETURN.CODE (please check the manual for exact syntax). It will be -1 if nothing is selected.

Comment: Yes, I am building a paragraph, I am learning from documentation from Rocket's website like the "Unidata Command Reference" or "UniData Using UniQuery" and existing paragraphs that were present on the system when I started.  Any other learning material recommendations would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for the information, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Philip's recommendation worked perfectly:

*create a savedlist to "Fall Back" on in case nothing is selected for what I actually want:*

```
SELECT PERSON SAMPLE 1  
SAVE.LIST savedlistFallBack
```

*create a savedlist for what I actually want*

```
SELECT PERSON WITH NAME EQ 'Bruce'   
SAVE.LIST savedlist1
```

*if no records were selected (no one was named Bruce) then overwrite the empty savedlist with my "Fall Back" one*

```
IF @SYSTEM.RETURN.CODE LT 0 THEN COPY.LIST savedlistFallBack savedlist1 -O
```